# Game Center saves my Clash of Clans account?

Tags: iphone, apple-id, games, game-center

I going to sell my iPhone. I want to know if all my progress in Clash of Clans will be saved within Game Center so that I can recover everything when I buy a new iPhone and login again in Game Center.

- Assume I am correctly logged in the Game Center with my Apple ID
- Achievements are visible in the Game Center app

I'm level 18 and have 790 trophies and I don't want to lose that progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have agreed to connect your Game Center account with Clash of Clans then yes, your progress is saved when swapping devices.